# Java While loop not adding correctly

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested-if

I can't figure out why this isn't adding up correctly each time it loops. There's also a problem with the while loop not outputting the sum when -9999 is typed in.

```
import java.util.*;
public class list 
{
   public static void main(String args []) 
   {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      int Number, Sum = 0;
      System.out.println("Enter the list of whole numbers, terminate by -9999> ");
      Number = sc.nextInt();
      Sum += Number;
      while (Number != -9999) 
      {
         if (Number > 1 && Number < 100)
         {
            Sum += Number;
            Number = sc.nextInt();
         } 
         else
           System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100");
         Number = sc.nextInt();
      }
      System.out.println("Sum is " + Sum);
   }
}
```

Comment: Try using a debugger.

Comment: Also, get your IDE to reformat your code - that will make the error much more obvious.

Comment: Also change `if (Number > 1 && Number < 100)` to `if (Number >= 1 && Number <= 100)`

Answer (score 5):

You are asking for a number potentially twice in a loop.  Once in the `if` block, and once *after* your `else` block.  Without parentheses, only the first statement is the block.  Instead of

```
else
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100");
  Number = sc.nextInt();
```

Try

```
else
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100");
    Number = sc.nextInt();
}
```

Also, your first number is added twice; remove the first addition from before the `while` loop.

Additionally, while it's legal and it's possibly your actual requirements, this line

```
if (Number > 1 && Number < 100)
```

won't accept `1` or `100`.  It's possible your requirements would include accepting both `1` and `100`, in which case the condition should be `Number >= 1 && Number <= 100`.

Incidentally, conventionally Java variables start with a lowercase letter, while classes start with an uppercase letter, meaning that the variables `Number` and `Sum` should be renamed `number` and `sum`, respectively.

Comment: Why dont you just remove the `sc.nextInt();` in the else statement altogether?

Comment: Better to take `Number = sc.nextInt();` outside the `if - else` block.

Answer (score 0):

1 Fixed When you are a planning to make a conditional loop better use `do while()`

2 There was a useless sc.nextInt() inside the `if (Number >= 1 && Number <= 100)` which was mixing up all your calculations

3 between 1 and 100 I suppose `Number >= 1 && Number <= 100` is what you need unless you don't want the application to accept 1 and 100

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int Number, Sum = 0;
            System.out.println("Enter the list of whole numbers, terminate by -9999> ");
            Number = sc.nextInt();

           do {
              if (Number >= 1 && Number <= 100)
              {
               Sum += Number;
              } 
             else
                System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 100");

              Number = sc.nextInt();
            } while (Number != -9999);
            System.out.println("Sum is " + Sum);
          }
```

Good Luck